# Ready state is still 1 though I got the Response

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, backbone.js

```
          toggleCompletedCheck : function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var key = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
            this.model = todoCollection.findWhere({
                key : key
            });
            this.model.toggle("completed", true);
            this.option.collection = todoCollection.add(this.model);
            var email = this.model.get("email");
            var title = this.model.get("title");
            var key = this.model.get("key");
            var status = this.model.get("status");
            var completed = this.model.get("completed");
            this.updateUserData(email, key, title, completed, status);
            returnValue = this.model.save();
            console.log(returnValue);
        },
```

The ready state is still 1 with in the function. The variable which I used is a window object(returnValue). When I print the object again in the console(from chrome browser) it shows me ready state 4 also allows me to access the responseText using returnValue.responseText. I am using the backbone.js to save the input to the backend. That returns the responseText as saved. But in turn, I am unable to access it when I try to it says undefined. How to get the responseText that I needed with in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's `model.save()` method is asyncronous. It returns a value (the javascript xhr object), but the request is not complete at return time.

To use the completed response, you would usually pass `success` or `error` callbacks to the `save` method ([docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)):

```
this.model.save(null, {
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        // do something with the response
    },
    error: function(model, response, options) {
        // do something with the response
    }
});
```

This can be a bit of an adjustment when you are used to `return`ing responses from your functions, but equivalent functionality is almost always possible using callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Since the data is not a JSON. I used as follows.
    this.model.save([],{
 dataType:"text",
 success:function(response) {
        returnValue = response.changed.Saved.xhr.responseText;     
        console.log(returnValue);
 return returnValue;
 },
        error:function() {}
});